# How can I make timer2 and timer3 to work at the same time but asynchrony?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a timer3 tick event:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```

Timer3 interval set to 10ms. It's going to the paint event of pictureBox1 and draw something.

And then I have timer2 tick event:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            if (counter == 200)
            {
                timer2.Enabled = false;
                return;
            }
            counter += 1;
            distance = (float)counter;
            CloudEnteringAlert.cloudalert(bitmapwithclouds, distance);
            double d = double.Parse(CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsdistance.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string s = string.Format("{0:0.0}", d);
            if (CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsfound == true)
            {
                label2.Visible = true;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                listBox1.Items.Add("Cloud detected at: " + CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsdistance.Text + " Kilometers from the coast");
                timesdetectedclouds += 1;
                label2.Text = timesdetectedclouds.ToString();
                if (CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsdistance.Text == "0")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    if (CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsfound == false)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                double dd = double.Parse(CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsdistance.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string ss = string.Format("{0:0.0}", d);
                listBox1.Items.Add("Cloud not detected at: " + CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsdistance.Text + " Kilometers from the coast");
                timesnotdetectedclouds += 1;
                label4.Text = timesnotdetectedclouds.ToString();
            }
        }
```

timer2 interval is set to 1000ms

The problem is when timer2 and timer3 are working the same time the drawings in the paint event of pictureBox1 are going very slow and only when timer2 stop then timer3 is realy on 10ms speed.

The question is how to make that both timers will work on the same time but each one with it's own real time? To put timer3 in a backgroundworker? If so how to do it with the backgroundworker?

This is pictureBox1 paint event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            anglecounter += 1;
            DrawLine(e.Graphics, anglecounter);
            if (null != mImage)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImage, mRect);
            }
            DrawRectangle(e.Graphics);
        }
```

This is the DrawLine method:

```
private void DrawLine(Graphics g, double angle)
        {

            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2f);
            int r = pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2;
            int X1 = pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2;
            int Y1 = pictureBox1.Size.Height / 2;
            Point pStart = new Point(X1, Y1);
            int X2 = (int)(X1 + r * Math.Cos((double)angle * Math.PI / 180));
            int Y2 = (int)(Y1 + r * Math.Sin((double)angle * Math.PI / 180));
            Point pEnd = new Point(X2, Y2);
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f), 0, 0, pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height);
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height);
            path = new GraphicsPath();
            path.AddPie(rec, (int)angle, -50);
            PathGradientBrush brush = new PathGradientBrush(path);
            brush.CenterPoint = pStart;
            brush.CenterColor = Color.LightGreen;
            brush.SurroundColors = new Color[] { Color.Empty };
            g.FillPath(brush, path);

        }
```

And the DrawRectangle method:

```
private void DrawRectangle(Graphics e)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
            {
                e.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect);
            }
        }
```

The draw rectangle if i want i'm drawing it manualy a rectangle on the pictureBox1.
The drawline method is drawing like a doppler radar and i want it to animate/move all the time aorund so that's why i'm using timer3 10ms and invalidating pictureBox1.

timer2 does something else it's doing another task i need to detect some pixels over the radar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class which is a thread-safe timer.

Regarding your UI modifications, you could use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) to modify parts of your UI in a thread safe environment.

Here's a small example (sorry for the late addition):

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer2 = new System.Timers.Timer(1000),
                            timer3 = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
public void Init()
{
    timer3.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // update your UI from the timer's thread
        pictureBox1.Invoke(
            new Action( 
                () =>
                {
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                }
            )
        );
    };

    timer2.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // Do other stuff with the UI by calling 
        // the appropriate Control invoke methods
    };

    timer2.Enabled = timer3.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are working in the UI thread it is not possible:
The UI can only be accessed from that thread and as one thread can only do one thing at a time you can not execute them in parallel.

What you could do is to only use the 10ms timer but count the iteration to also execute the "timer2 logic" every 1000ms...

Maybe you can explain your goal, because I think you are on the wrong path here - `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` every 10ms via timer "smells a little"...

Comment: ChrFin updated my question with pictureBox1 paint event and the emthods in the paint event and what i want it to do and why i need timer3 and what timer2 did.

Comment: 1) Do you really need 100 fps? Thats heavy on the CPU for WinForms... 2) You could use a `System.Timers.Timer` as suggested by Lucaci for `timer2` which does only "prepare stuff" in its own thread and then use it accordingly in the paint method.

Comment: ...BUT for me this kind of logic screams for "proper animation" and not "manual repainting". May you can use WPF which has native animation support?